# How can you identify a hidden Techie?

Tags: payday-3

The Techie is a new special unit who spawns in, hides behind an active camo shield, and spawns drones. Drones do a lot of damage since they constantly have the high ground. Finding and eliminating the Techie stops the drone spawns.

The problem is she's hard to find, and I currently find myself shooting at corners which doesn't actually seem to work. How can I find and eliminate a Techie?

Comment: I read the closer a player is to them, the more intense the HUD will be glitching out - like in this video here: https://youtu.be/B57QaxGpKoY?si=JztEglwzhx7xD5nT&t=703 That could help to track them down.

Comment: @TimmyJim That does appear to line up with what I've seen. I just assumed that was a heist specific effect (well, until the Techie gets added to other heists I suppose it is a heist specific effect)

Comment: For what it's worth also it seems to be a sphere, and she seems to have particular hiding spots to check, but I'm not 100% sure about all of the mechanics.